# Navigating list choices with vi bindings in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have recently migrated to zsh from bash and I'm loving it so far :)
I'm mostly use vi bindings to edit the commands and search the history.

Is there a way to navigate the auto-completion options using vi bindings(hjkl) instead of having to cycle through the options using TAB ?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit about your zsh configuration? Do you use the completion menu? Can you choose the completion option with the arrow keys? If so it is only a matter of specifying the correct keybindings